# Unable to use fossil through SSH, results in segmentation fault

Tags: git, svn, segmentation-fault, fossil

I'm trying to use [Fossil](http://www.fossil-scm.org/fossil/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki) on my shared sever through SSH. I've taken the following steps:

1. Created the folder fossil (in my user root, which gives the path /fossil/)
2. Uploaded the linux build of Fossil in /fossil/
3. Gave both the fossil folder and file CHMOD 755

However, using SSH and cd'ing into /fossil (which is the correct path), and then using any command only results in `Segmentation fault`.

[image: Image of the problem]

Any suggestions on how to solve this problem are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you download a pre-compiled binary package, or did you build from source? I'd first suspect that you are trying to use a pre-compiled build for a different OS.

Comment: @GregHewgill I downloaded the pre-compiled package. I'm completely new this area (SSH, linux and version control). I figured that the time had come to finally get familiar with VCS. :-)

Comment: If you want to learn a VCS and don't have a particular preference, you can learn Git online in your browser without installing anything at http://try.github.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was, like Greg said, most likely using the wrong build. [Bulding Fossil on my own](http://www.fossil-scm.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/build.wiki) solved my problem and now it works great.